# Why do we not use SI units for optical rotation of substances in solution?

Tags: optics, polarization, units, si-units, chirality

This question is with regards to a polarimetric approach in analysing the concentration of a substance in solution such as sugar in water.

I have been trying to find an answer to it through a little browsing but I could not really find anything useful. Most websites and books use dm for path-length of the solution in dm and concentration of the solution in g/ml. Why is this done? Why wasn't specific optical rotation of a substance in solution defined in terms of S.I. units rather than an awkward combination of c.g.s and other units?

Comment: What does "dm" stand for?

Comment: Probably for historical reasons. It also seems more practical to use these units for chemical analysis rather than the rather "bulky" kg/m^3 and m units. The SI system was created for a number of reasons, none of which is particularly relevant for the purposes of physics (other than in some cases for precision metrology) or even chemistry. It is "popular" because of the way we teach science in high school (which is at the layman level) and because it simplifies engineering.

Comment: @flippiefanus "dm" usually stands for "decimeter", i.e. 0.1m or 10cm. A 1dm^3 volume of water (=1 liter) weighs roughly 1kg. A typical polarimeter has a roughly 1dm path length, I believe... so it's kind of natural to use that as the base unit for this particular purpose.

Comment: It’s common for people working in various subfields to use whatever units they find convenient. For example, particle physicists like to measure energy in GeV, not joules. Astronomers like AUs, parsecs and light years, not meters. The fact that SI is a standard doesn’t mean its use is mandatory.

Comment: probably because in these units the quantities typically used in the field are closer to $O(1)$. I think it's actually more common to do something like this than to use base-SI units and add many zeros to all your numbers. I work on penning traps (which are a few cm in radius), and I usually use V/cm to describe electric fields applied by the electrodes and mV/cm to describe electric fields that are sources of error. This has the nice benefit that the field in V/cm is closer to the actual voltage, in volts, that is applied to the electrode.